Updating TOTP for teams account
I have several users with Teams account for which TOTP is set (as required) and needs to be newly set up, since the old app cannot export the key.
I had the first user go to the Additional Security Verification Page as suggested here.
Added a second TOTP so that there were two (there is no distinction between TOTP, I assumed the second entry was the new one. A date-time when the TOTP was added would be nice). The old TOTP was deleted, so there was only one left (the second one added).
After logging out and back in, the user is told that TOTP is required and TOTP needed to be set up before proceeding. So this third TOTP was set up to be able to proceed.
After that the third TOTP was deleted, and now login can be done with just the password and the only TOTP (the second one).
This is confusing to users, how can I prevent the third TOTP setup from happening. I prefer not to delete the original TOTP and then logout/login to get a TOTP prompt, as during that time the account would be single factor autenticated.
How can I prevent Azure from requiring this extra TOTP setup?

I helped two more users to move. The first of those users, was not prompted for a third TOTP, and things worked as required. Logging back in was delayed two minutes, so I thought that was the cause of the different behaviour.
However for the second of those users, a two minute delay did not help, so we had to login creating a third TOTP for that user. When that was deleted (the bottom one) from, expecting again that to be the latest. We could not login with the second TOTP set up for that account, but instead with the third (fortunately we had all three still available, just in case).
So the order of the TOTP entries is not necessarily the order in which they were added to the account. This makes things worse than I had feared.
